# JQuery Overlay not loading external webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I'm trying to get a plugin to work which opens up a webpage as an overlay rather than taking you away from the current page you are on. I cannot get the demo to work properly. It is demonstrated here:

http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/overlay/external.html

with a working demo here:

http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/overlay/external.htm

I can get this working perfectly for other pages which I host (relative paths), but I would like the overlay to open, for example, www.google.com - when I try this the overlay is simply blank. I am at a loss!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
   This is a jQuery Tools standalone demo. Feel free to copy/paste.
   http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/

   Do *not* reference CSS files and images from flowplayer.org when in
   production Enjoy!
-->
<head>
  <title>jQuery Tools standalone demo</title>

    <!-- include the Tools -->
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

  <!-- standalone page styling (can be removed) -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/media/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="/media/css/standalone.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="/media/css/overlay-apple.css"/>
<style>
    /* use a semi-transparent image for the overlay */
  #overlay {
    background-image:url(/media/img/overlay/transparent.png);
    color:#efefef;
    height:450px;
  }
  /* container for external content. uses vertical scrollbar, if needed */
  div.contentWrap {
    height:441px;
    overflow-y:auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body><!-- external page is given in the href attribute (as it should be) -->
<a href="external-content.htm" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">
  <!-- remember that you can use any element inside the trigger -->
  <button type="button">Show external page in overlay</button>
</a>

<!-- another link. uses the same overlay -->
<a href="external-content2.htm" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">
  <button type="button">Show another page</button>
</a>

<!-- overlayed element -->
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
  <!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag -->
  <div class="contentWrap"></div>
</div>

<!-- make all links with the 'rel' attribute open overlays -->
<script>
$(function() {

    // if the function argument is given to overlay,
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'darkred',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about your code?

Comment: I can think the problem is with cross domain browsing is not allowed.

Comment: I don't really know anything about jquery, just trying to implement this. Can I enable cross domain browsing?

Comment: If cross domain browsing is the catch you can't do nothin about it. Sorry...

Comment: Above and beyond plain old CORS issues, Google actively blocks attempts to frame or embed it (they send an `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header to prevent iframes from working for example).